# Script rules for outlook

Tags: outlook

I have a series of outlook rules which I need to automatically update for a group of people weekly.  I know I can export them and import them, but I'm looking for somewhere to define them and deploy them in some kind of script of code.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Are you taking about custom script?

Comment: @Brian Haven't tried anything just yet, wanting to see what is considered best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You have (3) options to manage **mailbox rules**:

1. [**Outlook Plugin**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff860622) supports most common rules. (*client or server rules*)
2. [**Exchange Management Shell**](http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/managing-inbox-rules-exchange-server-2010.html) (*server-side rules only*)
3. [**EWS Managed API**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597937%28v=exchg.80%29) (*server-side rules only*)